# I am getting error in admin panel

Tags: opencart, opencart2.3

I am getting error in admin panel while loading open cart admin panel

[image: http://prntscr.com/f79z72]

Please help me to solve it, I searched and found different solutions but it didn't help me to solve.

Answer (score 0):

try to use the URL without https. If you must use HTTPS, change the settings in your admin to reflect that (Use Secure Server) and then update the admin/config.php file.